# less.js causing 'unresponsive script' error in Firefox

Tags: jquery, symfony, less, assets

I have a 'unresponsive script' error on my pages since I started using twitter bootstrap and less.js script in my Symfony2 project.
Firebug tells me that the file that causes the error is less-1.3.0.min.js.
I am using assetic to handle my assets:

```
        {% block javascripts %}
        {% javascripts filter='?yui_js' output='js/all.js'
            '@YOPYourOwnPoetBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js'
            '@YOPYourOwnPoetBundle/Resources/public/js/bootstrap.min.js'
            '@YOPYourOwnPoetBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.cluetip.min.js'
            '@YOPYourOwnPoetBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery.imagesloaded.min.js'
            '@YOPYourOwnPoetBundle/Resources/public/js/less-1.3.0.min.js'
        %}
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
        {% endjavascripts %}
```

I checked for solutions to solve this kind of issue but all I read is that I have to debu my script using Firebug. In my case, it is a widely used script that is causing this issue, so I can't really debug it.

Any idea why this is happening, and how to solve this issue?

EDIT:

Here is the generated html for my page:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <script src="/yourownpoet/web/app_dev.php/js/all_jquery-1.7.2.min_1.js" type="text/javascript">
    <script src="/yourownpoet/web/app_dev.php/js/all_bootstrap.min_2.js" type="text/javascript">
    <script src="/yourownpoet/web/app_dev.php/js/all_jquery.cluetip.min_3.js" type="text/javascript">
    <script src="/yourownpoet/web/app_dev.php/js/all_jquery.imagesloaded.min_4.js" type="text/javascript">
    <script src="/yourownpoet/web/app_dev.php/js/all_less-1.3.0.min_5.js" type="text/javascript">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.yourownpoet.com/piwik/piwik.js">
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <noscript>&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src="http://www.yourownpoet.com/piwik/piwik.php?idsite=1" style="border:0" alt="" /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;</noscript>
    <script>
</body>
```

You can see the source code of the page at the address: http://www.yourownpoet.com
The path for the javascript file is: http://www.yourownpoet.com/js/all.js

Comment: Can you post what the actual generated HTML file looks like?  For those of us who don't know your system, what you've posted is meaningless so we can't help.  But if you post what the browser actually sees (do a View/Source in the browser), then many more folks could potentially help.

Comment: Inspect the `<head>` element with Firebug, and make sure that the path to the **less-1.3.0.min.js** file is correct. Have you tried appending the path for the js file to your url to see if you can access it through the browser?

Comment: @Jeemusu The path is correct, I can access the script through the browser.

Comment: There are no js files being loaded when I look at the url you provided.

Comment: @Jeemusu the path is www.yourownpoet.com/js/all.js Assetic combines all my js assets into one file. The line that triggers the error is line 60

Comment: ahh, well in that case... im not getting any errors in chrome or firefox. The page loads fine, and the all.js takes around 170ms to load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

compile your CSS in advance using less.js in node, lessc or if its an asp or PHP site consider a port - dotless or phpless respectively. it will speed your site and you'll never get these problems.

Comment: Yeah I was considering this option, but weird thing my pages don't render the same if I compile the less files with node or with javascript.. I must be doing something wrong right?

Comment: afraid so.. it should work this way - you'll have to compare the output css withwhat is output on the browser and work out what is changing and why.

Comment: Thank you using precompiled css solved the unresponsive script issue. I had to remove responsive.css for the elements to appear at the correct place in the page, now it is working fine.